# Sessão no PHP está resetando?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, session

Estou montando um sistema e quando a pessoa faz o login cria as sessões normalmente, exemplo:

```
$_Session['logado'] = 'S';
```

Porém quando redireciono para a página principal, a sessão simplesmente é zerada e fica vazia, *"sem nenhum valor"*.

O que pode ser?

[Login.php](https://www.sendspace.com/file/jfypjj)

[Checar_dados.php](https://www.sendspace.com/file/zegfcb)

[Index.php](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8cz55k)

Comment: Você está utilizando `session_start();` em todas as páginas?

Comment: Já sim.. inclusive estou usando o if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

Comment: `$_SESSION['logado'] = 'S'; `. Verifique também se você não está chamando `session_destroy`

Comment: No localhost funcionava normalmente, quando subi para o servidor na web que apareceram os problemas.

Comment: Espero que seja só um erro de digitação aqui no site, mas a grafia é `$_SESSION` e não `$_Session`. De qualquer forma, você precisa postar mais código, de preferência um [mcve], pq só pelo que está na pergunta, só dá pra tentar chutar respostas. Vendo o código original (ou um que gere o mesmo problema) talvez dê pra diagnosticar.

Comment: Foi apenas erro de grafia.. vou postar aqui para vocês verem.

Comment: Tente definir o caminho de armazenado usando `session_save_path`; Verifique se você não está usando `session_destroy` em algum outro arquivo; Verifique no navegador se está sendo gerado cookies com o ID da sessão. (Normalmente é `PHPSESSID`).

Comment: Como faço esses passos? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: O navegador está gerando o PHPSESSID, e só lembrando que no localhost funciona normalmente

Comment: Qual o tipo de servidor?